# django sortting_tags

Tags: django

I have sorting django sortingtags component on my page.

I want render differently my page depending on what field it is sorted by.

How can i implement that?

example:

```
{% autosort object_list %}
    <tr>
       <th>{% anchor first_name Name %}</th>
       <th>{% anchor creation_date Creation %}</th>
        ...
    </tr>
```

it become :

```
<tr>
    <th><a href="/path/to/your/view/?sort=first_name" title="Name">Name</a></th>
    <th><a href="/path/to/your/view/?sort=creation_date" title="Name">Creation</a></th>
    ...
</tr>
```

It renders me the same page depending on what link I cklicked but how can inspect what field it sorted by?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it. As far as the link looks like `/path/to/your/view/?sort=first_name`, so  you just need in views function make get from request: sorted_by=request.GET.get('sort') than send it in to template. Thats it!

Answer (score 0):

With Jinja2 templating engine you can have:

```
{% for tag in tags.order_by(sort_method) %}
    <a href="{{tag.get_absolute_url()}}">{{tag.name}}</a>
{% endfor %}
```

I'm not sure if django  templating will allow filter in the `{% for %}` clause, but you can try creating a filter that would add the `order_by` clause to the tags. 
Otherwise a custom template tag for iteration over the tag objects may be a solution. I'm not using django templating engine any more.